# Why did Zod ask for Lois Lane to come on their spaceship?

Tags: plot-explanation, man-of-steel, dc-extended-universe

In Man of Steel (2013), when Zod and his subordinates come to take Superman, they ask for Lois Lane too. But when they take her, they don't ask her anything. They just put her in some kind of prison, from which she escapes with the help of Jor-El. I could not understand why they took her in the first place. Can you explain that to me?

Comment: Good question. I thought it was maybe to study human physiology - but nothing was made of it.

Comment: I would suspect a potential hostage...

Comment: @Nobby And I thought rather *psychology* than physiology, as they might have seen how she and *Kal* interacted. So they might have just taken her as a possible hostage for controlling *Kal* or to see how he is related to her (and humans in general).

Comment: How about...Lazy writer?

Answer (score 18):

Two people know where Kal'El lived. Kal'El himself and of course, Lois. The ship in which he came to Earth was suspected to contain the codex and Zod needed to pinpoint the location. So when you need a piece of information, you collect all possible sources of it. Both of them gave away the location making it clear and credible to Zod where Clark lived. Zod is no fool, he is a war veteran. He is a general. Of course, it's not difficult for him to find Lois again but what's the point when she is available right in from of him.

Also, it was the only way for the story to progress and for Jor'El to instruct her.

Answer (score 5):

I suspect that they were still in search of the codex, and Zod knew that she was the only one close enough to Kal-El to possibly have this information. This is why they scanned her brain.

Answer (score 3):

There was a throwaway line that Zod had scanned her mind (along with Clark's) however not a lot is made of this.

I suspect the real reason she was there was so she could meet Jor El, so that they could find out how to defeat Zod and to give Clark the opportunity to save her life.

Comment: That mind scanning happened on the ship, I think.

Comment: @Keen indeed, my point was that that information gleaned from their minds wasn't used elsewhere in the film.  I suspect there was no other reason than it solved some story issues.

Comment: @Liath - Well, they did use the information gleaned to find Martha Kent.

Comment: @Keen nice spot!